# AJAX, JS, setInterval. Displaying data multiple times

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout, setinterval

**Hello and thank you for reading my post**

I have created a basic piece of AJAX. It looks like the following:

```
    <div id="name"></div>

    <script>
        async function get_name() {
            let server = await fetch("pageOneName")
            let data = await server.text()
            document.querySelector("#name").innerText = data
        }

        setInterval(get_name, 3000)
    </script>
```

as of now it doesn't really do much but retrieve my first name from the file/url

**What I would like to do is...**

Display my name multiple times (max 5 times) in multiple rows. One name after 3000, another after 4000, etc.

Like.

- Michael Anderson
- Michael Anderson
- Michael Anderson

What would my approach be here?

Comment: Append to the `innerText` instead of replacing it.

Comment: Use a global counter variable that counts the number of repetitions. When the count reaches 5, use `clearInterval()` to stop the timer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an interval of 3000, 4000, 5000 to create the name every second after 3 seconds and then create a counter to count the limit, when the limit is reached then clear the intervals.

```js
// initialize the variables.
var counter = 0;
var intervals = [];

// clear all intervals
function clearAllIntervals() {
    for (var id of intervals) {
        clearInterval(id);
    }
}

async function get_name() {
    let server = await fetch("pageOneName");
    let data = await server.text();

    let p = document.createElement("p");
    p.append(data);
    document.querySelector("#name").append(p);
    counter +=1;
    
    // Clear the counter and the intervals show 5 names.
    if (counter === 5){
        clearAllIntervals();
        counter = 0;    
    }
}

intervals.push(setInterval(get_name, 3000));
intervals.push(setInterval(get_name, 4000));
intervals.push(setInterval(get_name, 5000));
```

```html
<html> 
<body>
  <div id="name"></div>
</body>
</html>
```